# Animate view out, when UITableView starts scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a view controller who's view contains of a header view and a UITableView below it.
I do not want to put the header view in the table view for it to manage the scrolling, I want it to stay independent of the table view.
However I want to kind of hide it when scrolling down on the table view and my current solution looks like this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Void {
      //if contentOffset.y <= 0, table view is at the top, animate view in
      //else animate view out once
}
```

However since I am changing the layoutConstraint's constant to move out the view, it kind of interrupts scrolling and also pops in cells because it suddenly has a lot more space to show.

I thought about using a scrollview below both views that moves out the header view and passes the touches to the table view. However scroll views with auto layout content is kind of a pain in the ass...

Is there any topic on this or any idea what I could do? Basically like the navigation bar in Safari that scrolls away, when you scroll the content.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want the view to be independent from tableview? This is exactly what tableview is good at. Place the view inside the tableview as a regular view, add controls into it, then link this view and tableview with IBOutlet into view controller.

Then just set this view as tableview's tableHeaderView and you have your desired effect, header view will be positioned at the very top of tableview's contents and will scroll with it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    headerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    headerView.frame.size = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

Once you want to update the contents of the header view, just change its contents and set tableHeaderView again:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Let's say myLabel is a label inside the headerView
    myLabel.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus accumsan eros nec sem sagittis, vitae facilisis urna mattis."
    // Update the headerView size
    myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = myLabel.frame.width
    myLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
    headerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    headerView.frame.size = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

You could also place the view into its own Xib file and set it as tableHeaderView:

```
let views = UINib(nibName: "HeaderView", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
if views.count > 0, let headerView = views.first as? UIView {
    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

### The alternative with scroll view delegate

Place a view above the tableview and connect its top constraint to code (headerTopConstraint in example), then do something like this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    headerTopConstraint.constant += -scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if headerTopConstraint.constant > 0 {
        headerTopConstraint.constant = 0
        return
    }
    if -headerTopConstraint.constant > headerView.bounds.height {
        let diff = headerTopConstraint.constant + headerView.bounds.height
        headerTopConstraint.constant = -headerView.bounds.height
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -diff)
    }
    else {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    }
}
```

Header view will scroll up along with the tableview. Scrolling should still be feel smooth.

Comment: well I want to treat it individually, because its content is being fetched from a server, so I'd at some point need to update the header view height to reflect that change

Comment: I've updated the code to show how to update the contents of the header view after it was initially set.

Comment: I've also added an example with scrollViewDidScroll.

Comment: @frin  Thanks man.  your scroll view delegate code worked fine. Appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

this beauty when you display tableView bounce from center for all cell in UITableView :

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }
}
```